# Проблема с подсчетом голосов через словарь

Tags: python, словари

Есть файл в котором находятся имя человека и количество набранных голосов
**McCain 10

McCain 3

Alabama 19

Alabama 2

McCain 7**
я пытаюсь открыть файл и добавить через цикл имя и сколько набрал человек голосов,вот что я наделал...

```
with open("input (1).txt","r") as f:
    dict_1 = {}
    for e in f.read().split():
        if e.isalpha():
            v = e
        elif e.isdigit():
            k = e
        try:
            dict_1.update({v:k})
            print(dict_1)
        except:
            print(dict_1)
```

но что_то пошло не так :(
помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а чем не устраивает старый метод:

```
with open('input (1).txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    res = {}

    for line in lines:
        parts = line[:-1].split()
        res[parts[0]] = res.get(parts[0], 0) + int(parts[1])
```

через `line[:-1]` я отрезал `\n` (вроде он все таки во всех линиях присутствует), однако можно его убрать все таки

и можно сделать такой код:

```
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split()
    res[parts[0]] = (0 if parts[0] not in res else res[parts[0]]) + int(parts[1])
```

Comment: выходит ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @BELEЦKIY, посмотрите - я дописал свой ответ - можете попробовать второй код, но возможно дело исключительно в том, что я отрезаю последний символ `line[:-1]`, может этого делать и не надо, кроме того надо проверять, что строка может и не разбиваться на 2 слова и вообще быть нулевого размера. В общем посмотрите на какой именно строке у вас ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Так должно всё получится.

```
with open("input (1).txt","r") as f:
    dict_1 = {}
    for e in f.read().split():
        if e.isalpha():
            v = e
        elif e.isdigit():
            k = e
        try:
            dict_1[k] = v
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    print(dict_1)
```

Или же вот ваш чу-чуть поправлений:

```
with open("input (1).txt","r") as f:
    dict_1 = {}
    for e in f.read().split():
        if e.isalpha():
            v = e
        elif e.isdigit():
            k = e
            try:
                dict_1.update({k:v}) #Просто надо било k и v поменять местами
            except:
                pass
    print(dict_1) # и перенести сюда вивод dict_1
```